# Separable property of first-order PDE in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,y), v(x,y)$ be smooth functions of two variables. What is a necessary and sufficient differential condition in **only** $u,v$ for the first-order PDE

> $F'(x) - G'(y) - u(x,y)F(x) + v(x,y) G(y) = 0$ **($\ast$)**

to admit a non-trivial solution (i.e., $F,G$ not identically zero)?

This question comes up in a larger computation and may have a complicated condition.

One idea is to take $\partial_x \partial_y$ of **($\ast$)**, solve for $\color{red}{F'}$, and equate the two expressions for it; this gives a PDE with $G',F,G$. Repeating the process and solving for $G'$, I can obtain a complicated fourth-order differential equation in $u,v$ that is a necessary condition. I am hoping that there is a simpler condition or some relevant result.